# snakemake: reading input files from directory structure and creating wildcards

Tags: wildcard, snakemake

I am looking to create a pipeline that can take multiple input files, apply various tools to the output, and produce the desired results. My `input/` directory pattern looks like this:

```
  - organism_A
    - gene_1
      - seq_1.fasta
      - seq_2.fasta
    - gene_2
      - seq_3.fasta
  - organism_B
    - gene_1
      - seq_4.fasta
      - seq_5.fasta
      - seq_6.fasta
    - gene_3
      - seq_7.fasta
```

Currently, my solution reads only one wildcard - {sequence} - which corresponds to the entire path of a file in the input/ directory, such as `input/organism_A/gene_1/seq_1.fasta`

While it works well for a single rule, it becomes difficult to accurately specify the inputs and outputs when adding more rules.

I believe creating wildcards like `{organism}`, `{gene}` and `{sequence}` based on the files in the `input/` directory could be a good solution. Having three wildcards would make it easier for me to maintain output names and solve these issues.

I was wondering if there's a way to implement multiple wildcards based on the files in the `input/` directory?

```
import os

# Get a list of all .fasta files in the input directory and its subdirectories
def get_input_files(directory):
    input_files = []
    for root, _, files in os.walk(directory):
        for file in files:
            if not file.startswith('.') and file.endswith('.fasta'):
                # Get the relative path by stripping the "input/" prefix
                relative_path = os.path.relpath(os.path.join(root, file), directory)
                input_files.append(relative_path)
    return input_files

input_files = get_input_files("input")

rule all:
    input:  expand("output/{sequence}", sequence=input_files)


rule run_script:
    input:  sequence=lambda wildcards: f"input/{wildcards.sequence}"

    output: directory("output/{sequence}")

    shell:
        r"""
        my scipt which will produce files in output directory
        """
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across a very helpful [post](http://ivory.idyll.org/blog/2023-snakemake-slithering-wildcards.html) that explained things really well. It described a solution that better aligns with the Snakemake philosophy.

Below my adaptation:

```
files = glob_wildcards("tool1/input/{organism}/{gene}/{sequence}.fasta")


rule all:
    input:  expand("tool2/output/{organism}/{gene}/{sequence}/{sequence}.txt", organism=files.organism, gene=files.gene, sequence=files.sequence)
            

rule tool1:
    output: "tool1/output/{organism}/{gene}/{sequence}/{sequence}.txt"

    input:  "tool1/input/{organism}/{gene}/{sequence}.fasta"

    shell:
        r"""
        tool1 command

        """


rule tool2:
    output: "tool2/output/{organism}/{gene}/{sequence}/{sequence}.txt"

    input:  "tool1/output/{organism}/{gene}/{sequence}/{sequence}.txt"


    shell:
        r"""
        tool2 command

        """
```